# Unable to load Solidity contract using `compile_files` function with web3.py

Tags: erc-20, web3.py, python

I am new to ethereum block-chain. I created a **ERC20** smart-contract with help of **open-zeppelin** framework. I used py-solc package for solidity compilation with python. I imported compile_files function form solc. And use the function to compile solidity files. I got error when I intelize solidity file to compile.

So, my source code of python files is:-

```
import json
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider,TestRPCProvider
from solc import compile_source, compile_files
from web3.contract import ConciseContract

#Intelize solidity files to compile
compiled_sol = compile_files(["/home/anupam/Documents/workspace/DjangoProject/ico_application/users/contracts/old_type_contracts/DappToken.sol"])
print(compiled_sol.keys())

# Compiled solidity code
contract_interface = compiled_sol['/home/anupam/Documents/workspace/DjangoProject/ico_application/users/contracts/old_type_contracts/DappToken.sol:DappToken']


# web3.py instance
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545"))

# Instantiate and deploy contract
contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=contract_interface['abi'], bytecode=contract_interface['bin'])
print(contract)

# Get transaction hash from deployed contract
tx_hash =  contract.transact({'from': w3.eth.accounts[0]})
print(tx_hash)
```

Source Code of ERC20 Solidity file is:-

```
  pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/DetailedERC20.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/PausableToken.sol";
/**
 * The contractName contract does this and that...
 */
contract DappToken is MintableToken,PausableToken,DetailedERC20 {
            constructor(string _name, string _symbol, uint8 _decimals)
                    DetailedERC20(_name, _symbol, _decimals)
                    public
            {

                }

 }
```

I got error like this:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anupam/Documents/workspace/DjangoProject/ico_application/users/common/ERC20.py", line 7, in <module>
    compiled_sol = compile_files(["/home/anupam/Documents/workspace/DjangoProject/ico_application/users/contracts/old_type_contracts/DappToken.sol"])
  File "/home/anupam/Documents/envs/py_eth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/solc/main.py", line 135, in compile_files
    stdoutdata, stderrdata, command, proc = solc_wrapper(**compiler_kwargs)
  File "/home/anupam/Documents/envs/py_eth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/solc/utils/string.py", line 85, in inner
    return force_obj_to_text(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/anupam/Documents/envs/py_eth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/solc/wrapper.py", line 169, in solc_wrapper
    stderr_data=stderrdata,
solc.exceptions.SolcError: An error occurred during execution
> command: `solc --combined-json abi,asm,ast,bin,bin-runtime,clone-bin,devdoc,interface,opcodes,userdoc /home/anupam/Documents/workspace/DjangoProject/ico_application/users/contracts/old_type_contracts/DappToken.sol`
> return code: `1`
> stderr:

> stdout:
Invalid option to --combined-json: clone-bin
```

**Query 1**:- **Why this error came??**

**Quary 2**:- **Where I do mistakes in a code??**

Please resolve my query as soon as.

Comment: Which version of solc are you using?

Comment: I am using 0.4.24 solidity version

Comment: Yes, that's your contract versioning. What is the actual `solc` binary version?

Comment: It is also 0.4.24

Comment: Sorry I checked again my solc binary version is 0.4.25. So I have to degrade it.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to answer my own question.

**Why this error came??**

This error comes because I am using latest or pre-release version solidity binary version(**0.4.26**) in ubntu.

I uninstall this solidity version. And again install stable solidity binary version(**0.4.25**).

And again run python code so error is resolve.

**Where I do mistakes in a code??**

I was doing very silly mistakes. I was using pre-release solidity compiler.